# How to apply i18n on console message under Aurelia

Tags: internationalization, aurelia

I am working under Aurelia Framework.I want to apply i18N on console messages . 
I am using two languages "English" and "French"

```
Console.log("Hello World");
```

How i can print this message in french if user change language mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for the plugin](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/i18n#using-the-plugin) do contain exactly that example:

```
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';

  export class MyDemoVM {
    static inject = [I18N];
    constructor(i18n) {
      this.i18n = i18n;
      console.log(this.i18n.tr('mykey'));
    }
    ...
  }
```